# Is it possible to show all active jQuery bind()'s?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to show all active jQuery `bind()`'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show all data that jQuery elements have referenced with:

```
console.log(jQuery.cache);  // Logs the entire cache
```

Or for just the events (for those elements that have them):

```
for(name in jQuery.cache) {
    if(jQuery.cache[name]['events'])
       console.log(jQuery.cache[name]['events']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it at runtime using only the browser, use FireQuery: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

With jQuery:

```
var events = $('#element').data("events");
var firstClickEvent = events.click[0];
```

You can access all the event handlers like that for the element. To get every single one, you would have to enumerate the `events` variable.